# A general math problem that pertains to resistors in AC circuits

Tags: resistors, ac, voltage-measurement

I've been reading from [this](https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/resistor/res_8.html) website as a refresher on basic circuits and circuit components.

I have no problem understanding the properties of resistors in circuits and how to calculate V, I, or R, using Ohm's Law. This is not an issue.

However when I moved on from basic DC circuits to AC circuits all of the concepts are the same and I still have no problems understanding them, however from the website above I do have a basic simple question about their equations when the supply voltage is a sinusoidal waveform.

For example they show this equation:

[image: Instantaneous Voltage Across A Resistor]

My question has to pertain to how they are evaluating the sine. Is it

Sin(Omega) * t

or is it

Sin(Omega*t)

I know this seems to be something that is elementary and something simple, but this currently has me stumped...

Comment: \$ \sin(\omega \cdot t) \$

Comment: @WarrenHill Thank You. Yeah the website was using graphics and they didn't incorporate any parenthesis... I was searching for the answer while waiting for a response and when I came back to check; your comment was already here! Kudos!

Comment: \$ \omega \$ is angular frequency \$ \text{rad} \cdot \text{sec}^{-1} \$. \$ \ t \$ is is time in seconds.  \$ (\omega \cdot t) \$ is thus an angle and we take the sine of an angle.

Comment: @WarrenHill Yeah; I'm writing down notes from this website as it seems to be fairly decent on the overall behavior of circuits. It isn't over simplified nor super complex such as some college physics books will dive into quantum physics or mechanics while using advanced calculus. This is a good reference for me as I am planning on trying to write a circuit simulator / emulator in C++. I need to have all of the math correct first.

Comment: @WarrenHill Ah okay; I should of been able to figure that out; as it would be similar to Angular Momentum or Rotational Energy... But then again it's been well over 10 years since I looked in a college book...

Comment: Usually every thing after the sin is included when calculating the instantaneous value.  \$v_s =  169 sin (377 t - 45°)V\$ is the instantaneous equation for a 120\$V_{RMS}\$, 60Hz waveform starting at 45°.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat Yeah I got it now; I do know trig but when at the time of reading that website for a refresher and not seeing parenthesis I was just looking for a quick answer because I was taking notes from that page. I'm going to use that information to try and write a Circuit Simulator or Emulator in C++. I need to have the information of all the basic or general parts their properties, behaviors, responsibilities, effects, associations along with all of the math and of the underlying laws of physics behind them. This isn't going to be a small nor easy project.

Comment: It's sloppiness, but the brackets get left off as someone digitizes notes.